# xIs it possible to navigate between two switches/routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, framer-motion

I am studying fullstack development and am currently working with react, working with react framer-motion and when I navigate to a page with navbar it doesn't animate moving in.
trying to make a login page as the "/" on one `<Routes>` and the homepage as the "/" on the second.
basically a `<Routes>` for no nav bar pages.

`Current code:`

```
<AnimatePresence>
  <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
    <Route path="/" element={ <LoginPage/> } />        
    <Route path="/HomePage" element={ <HomePage/> }/>
  </Routes>
</AnimatePresence>
```

`Wanted code something like so:`

```
<AnimatePresence>
  <Routes path="/WONav" location={location} key={location.pathname}>
    <Route path="/" element={ <LoginPage/> } /> 
  <Routes/>
  <Routes path="/WONav" location={location} key={location.pathname}>        
    <Route path="/" element={ <HomePage/> }/>
  </Routes>
</AnimatePresence>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you mind making a sandbox?

Comment: update:
just tried, never used sandbox before but it gives me a bunch of dependencies problems. 
basically, the login page does not have a navigation bar, and the homepage does.
tried again, no luck (my error: `6001.1001.0000-dev-harmony-fb`)

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying the sandbox. What is wrong with your 'current code' example? The 'wanted code' example would render both routes at the same time, which doesn't seem like what you want to do.